# Circular linked list link rear to front without front reference

Tags: java, circular-list

[I am trying to implement number 6 in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcTS6.jpg)

I am basically trying to make a circular linked list and the way to do this would be to make a link from the rear node to the front node. However in this example they say not to use a front reference to the first node so I am not sure how to access the front node without a front reference. 
In the add and remove methods I would just put a line of code like
`rear.setLink(front);` However I do not know how to do this without a front reference. Here is my code so for, most of it is modified code from the textbook we are using

```
          /*
           * modified code from the book
         *
    */

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;


   import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
    //import edu.colorado.nodes.Node;
       public class CircularLinkedList<E> implements Cloneable {

       // File: LinkedQueue.java from the package edu.colorado.collections
  // Complete documentation is available from the LinkedQueue link in:
    //   http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/docs/



 // Invariant of the LinkedQueue class:
 //   1. The number of items in the queue is stored in the instance variable
 //      manyNodes.
 //   2. The items in the queue are stored in a linked list, with the front 
//      of the queue stored at the head node, and the rear of the queue at 
//      the final node.
//   3. For a non-empty queue, the instance variable front is the head 
//      reference of the linked list of items and the instance variable rear
//      is the tail reference of the linked list. For an empty queue, both 
//      front and rear are the null reference.

private int manyNodes=0; //numberOf Nodes in list initialized to 0
//private Node<E> front;
private Node<E> rear;


/**
* Initialize an empty queue.
* <b>Postcondition:</b>
*   This queue is empty.
**/   
public <Node>CircularLinkedList( )
{
  //front = null;
  rear = null;

}


/**
* Put a new a new item in this queue. 
* @param item
*   the item to be pushed onto this queue 
*  <b>Postcondition:</b>
*   The item has been pushed onto this queue.
* @exception OutOfMemoryError
*   Indicates insufficient memory for increasing the queue's capacity.
* <b>Note:</b>
*   An attempt to increase the capacity beyond
*   <CODE>Integer.MAX_VALUE</CODE> will cause the queue to fail with an
*   arithmetic overflow.
**/    
public void add(E item)
{
  Node cursor;
    if (isEmpty( ))
   {  // Insert first item.
     rear = new Node<E>(item, null);
//rear = front;
    }
   else
   {  // Insert an item that is not the first.
      rear.addNodeAfter(item);
      rear = rear.getLink( );  
      //for(cursor =rear; curs
     // rear.setLink(CircularLinkedList.listposition(0)); //make link to front creating a           circular linked List

   }
   manyNodes++;
   }


/**
* Generate a copy of this queue.
* @return
*   The return value is a copy of this queue. Subsequent changes to the
*   copy will not affect the original, nor vice versa. Note that the return
*   value must be type cast to an <CODE>LinkedQueue</CODE> before it can be used.
* @exception OutOfMemoryError
*   Indicates insufficient memory for creating the clone.
**/ 
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public CircularLinkedList<E> clone( )       
{  // Clone a LinkedQueue<E>.
  CircularLinkedList<E> answer;
  Object[ ] cloneInfo;

  try
  {
     answer = (CircularLinkedList<E>) super.clone( );
  }
  catch (CloneNotSupportedException e)
  { 
     // This exception should not occur. But if it does, it would probably indicate a
     // programming error that made super.clone unavailable. The most comon error
     // The most common error would be forgetting the "Implements Cloneable"
     // clause at the start of this class.
     throw new RuntimeException
     ("This class does not implement Cloneable");
  }

  cloneInfo = Node.listCopyWithTail(rear);
 // answer.front = (Node<E>) cloneInfo[0];
  answer.rear = (Node<E>) cloneInfo[1];

  return answer;
}        


/**
* Determine whether this queue is empty.
* @return
*   <CODE>true</CODE> if this queue is empty;
*   <CODE>false</CODE> otherwise. 
**/
public boolean isEmpty( )
{
  return (manyNodes == 0);
}


/**
* Get the front item, removing it from this queue.
* <b>Precondition:</b>
*   This queue is not empty.
* @return
*   The return value is the front item of this queue, and the item has
*   been removed.
* @exception NoSuchElementException
*    Indicates that this queue is empty.
**/    
public E remove( )
{
  E answer;

  if (manyNodes == 0)
     // NoSuchElementException is from java.util and its constructor has no argument.
     throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue underflow");
 answer = rear.getData( );
 // front = front.getLink( );
  manyNodes--;
  if (manyNodes == 0)
     rear = null;
  return answer;
   //rear.setLink(front);
}


/**
* Accessor method to determine the number of itaems in this queue.
*  @return
*   the number of items in this queue
**/ 
public int size( )   
{
  return manyNodes;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
 CircularLinkedList c1 = new CircularLinkedList();
 c1.add(1);
 c1.add(2);
 c1.add(3);
 c1.remove();
 System.out.println("the data in the rear is " + c1.rear.getData());
 //System.out.println("the data in the front is " + c1.front.getData());
// System.out.println("the data in node after rear is  " + c1.rear.getLink().getData());
 //System.out.println("this is because the rear links to the front making the Linked List circular");
 }
}
```

Below is the Node Class Code (Dosn't need to be edited)

```
  class Node<E>
  {
  // Invariant of the Node class:
  //   1. Each node has one reference to an E Object, stored in the instance
  //      variable data.
  //   2. For the final node of a list, the link part is null.
  //      Otherwise, the  link part is a reference to the
  //      next node of the list.
  private E data;
  private Node<E> link;

/**
* Initialize a node with a specified initial data and link to the next
* node. Note that the initialLink may be the null reference,
* which indicates that the new node has nothing after it.
* @param initialData
*   the initial data of this new node
* @param initialLink
*   a reference to the node after this new node--this reference may be null
*   to indicate that there is no node after this new node.
* @postcondition
*   This node contains the specified data and link to the next node.
**/
public Node(E initialData, Node<E> initialLink)
{
  data = initialData;
  link = initialLink;
 }


/**
* Modification method to add a new node after this node.
* @param element
*   the data to place in the new node
* @postcondition
*   A new node has been created and placed after this node.
*   The data for the new node is element. Any other nodes
*   that used to be after this node are now after the new node.
* @exception OutOfMemoryError
*    Indicates that there is insufficient memory for a new
*   Node.
**/
public void addNodeAfter(E element)
{
  link = new Node<E>(element, link);
}


/**
* Accessor method to get the data from this node.
* @param - none
* @return
*   the data from this node
**/
public E getData( )
{
  return data;
}


/**
* Accessor method to get a reference to the next node after this node.
* @param - none
* @return
*   a reference to the node after this node (or the null reference if there
*   is nothing after this node)
**/
public Node<E> getLink( )
{
  return link;
}


 /**
 * Copy a list.
 * @param source
 *   the head of a linked list that will be copied (which may be
 *   an empty list in where source is null)
 * @return
 *   The method has made a copy of the linked list starting at
 *   source. The return value is the head reference for the
 *   copy.
 * @exception OutOfMemoryError
 *   Indicates that there is insufficient memory for the new list.
 **/
 public static <E> Node<E> listCopy(Node<E> source)
 {
  Node<E> copyHead;
  Node<E> copyTail;

  // Handle the special case of the empty list.
  if (source == null)
     return null;

  // Make the first node for the newly created list.
  copyHead = new Node<E>(source.data, null);
  copyTail = copyHead;

  // Make the rest of the nodes for the newly created list.
  while (source.link != null)
  {
     source = source.link;
     copyTail.addNodeAfter(source.data);
     copyTail = copyTail.link;
  }

  // Return the head reference for the new list.
  return copyHead;
}


 /**
 * Copy a list, returning both a head and tail reference for the copy.
 * @param source
 *   the head of a linked list that will be copied (which may be
 *   an empty list in where source is null)
 * @return
 *   The method has made a copy of the linked list starting at
 *   source.  The return value is an
 *   array where the [0] element is a head reference for the copy and the [1]
 *   element is a tail reference for the copy.
 * @exception OutOfMemoryError
 *   Indicates that there is insufficient memory for the new list.
 **/
 public static <E> Node<E>[ ] listCopyWithTail(Node<E> source)
 {
  Node<E> copyHead;
  Node<E> copyTail;
 //Node<E>[ ] answer = (Node<E>[]) new Object[2]; Causes ClassCastException!
  Node<E>[ ] answer = createArray(null, null);

  // Handle the special case of the empty list.
  if (source == null)
     return answer; // The answer has two null references .

  // Make the first node for the newly created list.
  copyHead = new Node<E>(source.data, null);
  copyTail = copyHead;

  // Make the rest of the nodes for the newly created list.
  while (source.link != null)
  {
     source = source.link;
     copyTail.addNodeAfter(source.data);
     copyTail = copyTail.link;
  }

  // Return the head and tail references.
  answer[0] = copyHead;
  answer[1] = copyTail;
  return answer;
  }


 /**
 * Compute the number of nodes in a linked list.
 * @param head
 *    the head reference for a linked list (which may be an empty list
 *   with a null head)
 * @return
 *   the number of nodes in the list with the given head
 * @note
 *   A wrong answer occurs for lists longer than Int.MAX_VALUE.
 **/
 public static <E> int listLength(Node<E> head)
 {
  Node<E> cursor;
  int answer;

  answer = 0;
  for (cursor = head; cursor != null; cursor = cursor.link)
     answer++;

  return answer;
 }


/**
* Copy part of a list, providing a head and tail reference for the new copy.
* @param start/end
*   references to two nodes of a linked list
* @param copyHead/copyTail
*   the method sets these to refer to the head and tail node of the new
*   list that is created
* @precondition
*   start and end are non-null references to nodes
*   on the same linked list,
*   with the start node at or before the end node.
* @return
*   The method has made a copy of the part of a linked list, from the
*   specified start node to the specified end node. The return value is an
*   array where the [0] component is a head reference for the copy and the
*   [1] component is a tail reference for the copy.
* @exception IllegalArgumentException
 *   Indicates that start and end do not satisfy
*   the precondition.
* @exception OutOfMemoryError
*   Indicates that there is insufficient memory for the new list.
**/
   public static <E> Node<E>[ ] listPart(Node<E> start, Node<E> end)
  {
  Node<E> copyHead;
  Node<E> copyTail;
  Node<E> cursor;
 //Node<E>[ ] answer = (Node<E>[]) new Object[2]; Causes ClassCastException!
  Node<E>[ ] answer = createArray(null, null);

  // Check for illegal null at start or end.
  if (start == null)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("start is null");
  if (end == null)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("end is null");

  // Make the first node for the newly created list.
  copyHead = new Node<E>(start.data, null);
  copyTail = copyHead;
  cursor = start;

  // Make the rest of the nodes for the newly created list.
  while (cursor != end)
  {
     cursor = cursor.link;
     if (cursor == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
        ("end node was not found on the list");
     copyTail.addNodeAfter(cursor.data);
     copyTail = copyTail.link;
   }

   // Return the head and tail references
  answer[0] = copyHead;
   answer[1] = copyTail;
   return answer;
  }


/**
* Find a node at a specified position in a linked list.
* @param head
*   the head reference for a linked list (which may be an empty list in
*   which case the head is null)
* @param position
*   a node number
* @precondition
*   position > 0.
* @return
*   The return value is a reference to the node at the specified position in
*   the list. (The head node is position 1, the next node is position 2, and
*   so on.) If there is no such position (because the list is too short),
*   then the null reference is returned.
* @exception IllegalArgumentException
*   Indicates that position is zero.
**/
   public static <E> Node<E> listPosition(Node<E> head, int position)
   {
   Node<E> cursor;
  int i;

  if (position == 0)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("position is zero");

  cursor = head;
  for (i = 1; (i < position) && (cursor != null); i++)
     cursor = cursor.link;

  return cursor;
  }


/**
* Search for a particular piece of data in a linked list.
* @param head
*   the head reference for a linked list (which may be an empty list in
*   which case the head is null)
* @param target
*   a target to search for
* @return
*   The return value is a reference to the first node that contains the
*   specified target. If the target is non-null, then the
*   target.equals method is used to find such a node.
*   The target may also be null, in which case the return value is a
*   reference to the first node that contains a null reference for its
*   data. If there is no node that contains the target, then the null
*   reference is returned.
**/

 public static <E> Node<E> listSearch(Node<E> head, E target)
 {
  Node<E> cursor;

  if (target == null)
  {  // Search for a node in which the data is the null reference.
     for (cursor = head; cursor != null; cursor = cursor.link)
        if (cursor.data == null)
           return cursor;
  }
  else
  {  // Search for a node that contains the non-null target.
     for (cursor = head; cursor != null; cursor = cursor.link)
        if (target.equals(cursor.data))
           return cursor;
  }

  return null;
  }


/**
* Modification method to remove the node after this node.
* @param - none
* @precondition
*   This node must not be the tail node of the list.
* @postcondition
*   The node after this node has been removed from the linked list.
*   If there were further nodes after that one, they are still
*   present on the list.
* @exception NullPointerException
*   Indicates that this was the tail node of the list, so there is nothing
*   after it to remove.
**/
public void removeNodeAfter( )
{
  link = link.link;
}


/**
* Modification method to set the data in this node.
* @param newData
*   the new data to place in this node
* @postcondition
*   The data of this node has been set to newData.
*   This data is allowed to be null.
**/
  public void setData(E newData)
  {
  data = newData;
   }


/**
* Modification method to set the link to the next node after this node.
* @param newLink
*   a reference to the node that should appear after this node in the linked
*   list (or the null reference if there is no node after this node)
* @postcondition
*   The link to the node after this node has been set to newLink.
*   Any other node (that used to be in this link) is no longer connected to
*   this node.
**/
  public void setLink(Node<E> newLink)
 {
  link = newLink;
  }



 /**
 * Create an array of Node<E> objects.  This is the only way that
* I've found to create such an array that doesn't cause a
* ClassCastException at run time.  In the textbook, I used:
*  // Node<E>[ ] answer = (Node<E>[]) new Object[2];
* but this approach now seems to fail.  I'll keep looking for
* other solutions!
**/
 private static <E> Node<E>[ ] createArray(Node<E>... nodes)
 {
  return nodes;
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the first node, link it to itself. Although there's only one node it would make it a circular list.

> first -> first

Then when you add the second node your code would work to the keep nodes in a circular list.

> first -> second -> first

And the value in rear will be the second node.

```
public void add(E item) {
    Node cursor;
    if (isEmpty( )) {
       // Insert first item.
        rear = new Node<E>(item, null);
        rear.setLink(rear);    // <=== add a link to itself to make it circular
    }
    else {
        // Insert an item that is not the first.
        rear.addNodeAfter(item);
        rear = rear.getLink( );  
    }
    manyNodes++;
}
```

When you want to remove the front node. Take the link from rear (this will give you the front) then set the link in rear to the link in front (this will point you to the one after the front).

> first -> second -> third -> first

becomes

> second -> third -> second

becomes

> third -> third

You need to take care to check if the list only has one item. If it does then you would clear the list by setting rear to null.

```
public E remove() {
    if (rear == null) {
        // NoSuchElementException is from java.util and its constructor has no argument.
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue underflow");
    }

    E answer = rear.getLink().getData();

    if (rear.getLink() == rear) {
        // this is the last item in the list
        rear = null;
    }
    else {
        // point rear to the one after front so that front is removed
        rear.setLink(rear.getLink().getLink());
    }
    manyNodes--;
    return answer;
}
```

The static methods in the Node class assume that rear has a link of null. This won't be the case for a circular list. So these methods will keep on looping around the list over and over again. So be careful if you plan to use them.

Comment: thanks man! Is there a way to do this without a front reference in the remove method?

Comment: You could replace `front` with `rear.getLink()`

Comment: ok thanks.. that works.. I made a reference variable called link instead of front , idk if that would be ok to do as well